# What happens if I reload after using the Golden Key?

Tags: borderlands-2

I'm wondering if it's possible to reload after opening the chest, (such as by quitting the game from the PS3 menu) and still keep your Golden key. I know you won't be able to keep the weapons you found inside, but will you be able to keep the key, or is it tied to your account and lost permanently the moment you use it?

I ask because I don't want to open the chest and find a shotgun and a pistol, and be stuck with really nice weapons I detest, but I'm afraid that if I test it I could lose the key AND the weapons by exiting the game without saving.

Just wondering if anyone had tried it.

Comment: I have't tried it, but I'm fairly certain that it would be gone. The keys are a kind of currency, and once you spend currency, the game typically saves.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The game is saved right when you use the key so you can't save your keys that way.

I found that out the hard way when I first opened the chest with my key (when I didn't want to yet), restarted (without picking up the loot) and found out I lost my key and had no loot.

Comment: Have an upvote as consolation :P

Comment: I'm over it. It was a while back when I was level 12 or so. You can imagine how weak the loot was. Just a little bummed that I couldn't save it for later when I was at higher levels. But I'll have better loot by then.

Comment: I think the fact that you didn't have the weapons means the game isn't saved right away.

Comment: I figured as much. Thanks for the confirmation, and... sorry for your loss. :)

Comment: @kotekzot: It does. What happened was that it saved when I hit use, the chest opened but I didn't pick up the loot and it never got the chance to save again. I immediately quit the second I realized I used up my key hoping I could save it (on PC, you can quit without saving using `Alt + F4`).